# Getting following errors buliding registration form using html5 and css.Getting following errors

Tags: html, css, registration

Getting following errors buliding registration form using html5 and css.
Registraion form with input type fields,one dropdown list and button.
Getting following errors buliding registration form using html5 and css.
Registraion form with input type fields,one dropdown list and button.
Getting following errors buliding registration form using html5 and css.
Registraion form with input type fields,one dropdown list and button.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
      <title>Destiny</title>
      <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    
     <body>
    
      <h1>Registration Form</h1>
    
     <div id="container">
      <form>
    
       <label for="name"  >Name:</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="select" value=""style=" margin-left:120px;float:centre; position:relative;"></br></br>
    
      <label for="date" >Date of Birth:</label>
      <input type="date" name="date"  id="select" value="" style=" margin-left:75px;padding-right:15px;float:centre; position:relative;"></br></br>
    
      <label for="country">Country:</label>
      <input list="browsers" name="country"  style="margin-left:110px;position:absolute;">
      <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="India"></option>
        <option value="United States"></option>
        <option value="United Kingdom"></option>
        <option value="Austraila"></option>
        <option value="France"></option>
      </datalist></br></br>
    
      <label for="phone">Phone number:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" style="margin-left:65px;"></br></br>
    
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" style="margin-left:118px;float:centre;"></br></br>
    
      <label>Website:</label>
      <input type="url" style="margin-left:105px;float:centre;"></br></br>
    
     </form>
    </div>
    
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS file

```
body {
        /*  background-image: url("https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5695/22447126166_2db1545ed4_b.jpg");*/
     
     background-color: #e0d8cc;
    
    }
    header{
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: #cc6533;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    header a:hover{
        color: orange;
    }
    h1{
        margin: 13px 15px 12px 13px;
    
        color:black
    }
    input{
        border: 1px solid #cc6533;
      border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
    }
    form{
        margin: 47px 0px 0px 34px;
    }
    #container{
        margin-left: 11px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #cc6533
    }
    button{
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: none;
        padding: 4px 9px 5px 10px;
        margin: 6px 0px 0px 452px;
        background-color: #cc6533;
    }
    select{
        border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #cc6533;
        padding: 1px;
    }
```

Testclass
test_webpage.py

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pytest
    import pickle
    import requests
    
    class TestWebpage:
        @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
        def get_soup(self):
            index_page = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/index.html")
            soup_index = BeautifulSoup(index_page.content, 'html.parser')
            self._index = soup_index
            
        # testing index.html
        def test_indexpage(self):
            assert self._index.find_all('form')
            assert self._index.body.h1.string=='Registration Form'
            site = self._index.find('form')
            assert self._index.find('form')
            site1 = site.find_all('input')
            count = 0
            for input in site1:
                count +=1
            assert count==6
            assert self._index.find('datalist')
            site2=site.find_all('datalist')
            site3=self._index.find_all('option')
            count = 0
            for option in site3:
                count +=1
            assert count==5
            assert self._index.find_all('input', {'type': 'text'})
            assert self._index.find_all('input', {'type': 'date'})
            assert self._index.find_all('input', {'type': 'email'})
            assert self._index.find_all('input', {'type': 'tel'})
            assert self._index.find_all('input', {'type': 'url'})
```

> Getting following error

```
            def test_indexpage(self):
        
                assert self._index.find_all('form')
        
                assert self._index.body.h1.string=='Registration Form'
        
                site = self._index.find('form')
        
                assert self._index.find('form')
        
                site1 = site.find_all('input')
        
                count = 0
        
                for input in site1:
        
                    count +=1
        
        >       assert count==6
        
        E       assert 1 == 6
        
        test/test_webpage.py:23: AssertionError
```

Comment: What was the assert count ==6 statement for? count is 1 and therefore the assertion fails. Perhaps youR problems are in the python code and it may be useful to tag your question python as well.

Comment: This question is from heckrrank so I am restricted to make any changes in their code I have to modify(html file only) my code to pass their given conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the break tag in the HTML page is incorrectly used throughout your code.

It should be `<br>` instead of `</br>`

Comment: working now thanks for correcting my small(stupid) mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  <h1>Registration Form</h1>
```

This tag has to be placed inside the  tag

```
 <div id="container">
```

## Registration Form

.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Destiny</title>
  <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 //write your code here
 
 <h1>Registration Form</h1>
 <div id="container">
  <form>
    <label for="name">Name:  </label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth:  </label>
    <input type="date" name="dateofbirth">
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="country">Country:  </label>
    <input list="browsers" name="country">
    <datalist id="browsers">
       <option value="india">India</option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="austraila">Austraila</option>
      <option value="France">France</option>
    </datalist>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="phonenumber">Phone number: </label>
    <input type="tel" name="phonenumber">
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="email">Email:  </label>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="website">website:  </label>
    <input type="url" name="website">

  </form>
 </div>

 <button type="submit">Submit</button>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your HTML page. The compiler is looking for the name  of the form, Use this:

```
    <h1>Registration Form</h1>    
    <form id="registrationForm" name="Registration Form">
    ....
    ....
    </form>
    <input type="submit" form="registrationForm">
```

Sorry for the late answer, but it worked for me.